# Is there any twitter api that can return urls of photos/media associated with a twitter account?

Tags: ios, twitter

I am working on an iOS app that I want to stream photos/pics in a users twitter account. For example, you can view a user's recent photos via https://twitter.com/#!/users_twitter_screenname/media/grid. I am wondering if there is such an api can work this out.

Basically, is there such an api can return the urls of these photos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out which twitter API to use to get the media url of a specified user. The API is the [GET statuses/user_timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) with the `include_entities` parameters set to true. The API will return 200 status of a user, if you want to get more result, you can use the `page` parameter to paginate through all twitter results.

Here are some sample codes using `twitter` API in iOS 5.

```
#include<Twitter/Twitter.h>
-(void)getUserTimeLine
{
    TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc]
                                 initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&include_entities=true&trim_user=true&page=1"] 
                                 parameters:nil 
                                 requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

    if ([urlResponse statusCode]==200) 
        {
            //Request succeed, then need to parse the json data returned. 
            //Do some parsing here.
        }
    else
        {
            //Request failed.
            NSLog(@"HTTP response data:%i\n.",[urlResponse statusCode]);
        }        
    }];
}
```